# The for loop in the function isn't correct

Tags: javascript

Create a function called isIsogram that takes one argument, a word to test if it's an isogram. This function should return a boolean indicating whether it is an isogram (true) or not (false). Here is the code accordingly:

```
function isIsogram(word){
    if (typeof word !== 'string'){
      return 'Argument should be a string';
    }

    if (word === ' '){
      return false;
    }

    else{
      for(var i=0; i<word.toLowerCase().length; i++){
        if (word.charAt(i)>1){
          return false;
        }
        else{
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(isIsogram('Akosombo'));
```

'Akosombo' should return false but it's returning true.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is logically irrelevant:

```
word.charAt(i) > 1
```

All these evaluate to `false`:

- `'A' > 1`
- `'k' > 1`
- `'o' > 1`
- `'s' > 1`
- `'o' > 1`
- `'m' > 1`
- `'b' > 1`
- `'o' > 1`

More hints:

1. You should check the definition of [Isogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogram).
2. You should only `return true` after the `for` loop.

Comment: I know what an isogram is, I only needed help with the for loop because it's the controller. Anyway ,thanks for the hints @aaron but I got it sorted already and yes you are right about where the last return statement should be

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogram), An isogram is a word or phrase without a repeating letter.

So here you must check for the repeating letters. Here is my approach (with a little change in your code) to check whether it is isogram or not?

```
function isIsogram(word) {
    var matches = 0;
    var count = 0;
    if (typeof word !== 'string') {
        return 'Argument should be a string';
    }

    if (word === ' ') {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < word.toLowerCase().length; i++) {
            matches = word.match(new RegExp(word.charAt(i), 'gi'));
            if (matches.length > 1)
                count++;
        }
        if (count > 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
isIsogram('Akosombo');
```

And result will be false with word 'Akosombo', because it has repeating character i.e 'o'.

Comment: Your code didn't work at all when I tested it but thanks, I already solved it yesterday

Comment: Oh yes, you are right but it failed all the tests I ran it with when I tested it somewhere but it printed a boolean and undefined when I ran it in the terminal. I don't think it should print undefined after the boolean

Comment: @skm It prints `undefined` because you `console.log(false)` instead of `return false`.

Comment: You're welcome. Your algorithm is wrong though - try `isIsogram('OOP')`.

Comment: Glad you corrected it but 'OOP' returned false here. I already called toLowerCase on the parameter so any argument passed in will be dealt with accordingly

Comment: @skm mind you I didn't use what I posted directly, I added another nested for loop to check for n+1. So I used two for loops

Comment: danoseun and @aaron, you can check it now. I updated the code.